# Modelling Round Curved Edges

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make rounded off inner edges on a mesh. But I'n not on the right track, (I'm avoiding to use the Boolean.) I'm trying to achieve it using correct geometry. It does look a little bit decent, but that's after bumping up the viewport subdivision,and I've added way too many loop cuts. What would be the best modelling approach?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: First of all, what's the purpose of your mesh, in terms of "correct" geometry? Rendering, 3D game asset, 3D printing? All three of them might have different requirements, when it comes to "correct" geometry ([**please read this**](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) if you want to know how you can help us to give good answers). Second question: Why not make use of Blender's built-in Bevel tool?

Comment: I have no purpose for the specific mesh, I'm trying to understand good way how to solve a problem in this situation. I made the same mesh this time using Boolean and then bevel which is clean with no shading issues, which I could of done in the first place,  but I wanted to see more techniques without taking the easy way, since I'm a novice user of Blender. 

https://ibb.co/sR9Pytq

Answer (score 0):

What about such topology? All quads.
[image]

Comment: All quads, really ?

Comment: I'd like to see your technique how you achieved this shape. But what worries me, is once the subdivision modifier gets added, that corner where you did the bevel, will look messed up. Also you have stray vertices..

https://ibb.co/jJNWHcH

Comment: I can spot at least 4 ngons. Some of those shapes might have 4 vertices, but that doesn't make them into quads. Furthermore, those vertices that are located "within" the base shape most definitely lead to shading problems.